# File.listFiles throws NullPointer

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I'm recursively searching for a file in my computer.

```
 private static File findFileDepthSearch(File dir, String fileName) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) {
            return f;
        }
    }
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            File res = findFileDepthSearch(f, fileName);
            if(res != null)
            {
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After going two levels deep, `dir.listFiles` returns `null`. However, this shouldn't be the case because the file in question is in fact a directory. When I try to enter it in the console, it says **Acess denied**, but according to the javadocs security issues should throw an exception. What am I missing here?
Adding this in

```
if(files==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

fixes the issue, but why is this necessary?

Comment: Indeed listFiles may return null. Simply check for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: lol thats not a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) states "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

If you do not have access to the directory at the file system level, that qualifies as an "I/O error" and so the function will return `null`.

It only throws a `SecurityException` if you create a `SecurityManager` and configure it to restrict access to that directory.